# Resizing component Rating of gluon

Tags: mobile, javafx, width, rating, gluon

I'm trying to resize a Rating component by css and by code with this instruction:

```
Rating rating= new Rating();
rating.setPrefWidht(100);
rating.setPrefHeight(40);
```

But in both cases the rating doesn't resize!
Any helps?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

As the `Rating` control seems to ignore the set prefSize, you have to set the size of the rating buttons, e.g.:

```
.rating > .container > .button{
    -fx-min-width: 20;
    -fx-min-height: 20;

    -fx-max-width: 20;
    -fx-max-height: 20;
}
```

Comment: thank you, there is a way to resize the container of the button in height? I try in the similar way you wrote but doesn't work.

Comment: `.rating > .container {  
 -fx-max-height:  yourHeight;
}` ? [ScenicView](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) is a great help in testing / understanding UI`s